# Area Bounded Between $y^2=8x + 16$, $y^2=-4x + 28$ and the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, area

I am just getting started with applications of integration, and I am stuck upon a footling question. Required to find the area bounded between $y^2=8x + 16$, $y^2=-4x + 28$, and the $x$-axis. The way I thought of solving this at first was to integrate with respect to $y$:

both curves have equal ordinates at points:
$\smash[b]{\bigl( \frac{y^2+16}{8}, y \bigr)}$ for the curve
$y^2=8x + 16$, and
$\smash[b]{\bigl( \frac{28-y^2}{4}, y \bigr)}$
for the curve $y^2=-4x + 28$.

So the length of the horizontal strip connecting any two of those points is
$$
\frac{28-y^2}{4} - \frac{y^2+16}{8} 
= 5 - \frac{3y^2}{8}. 
$$

The point of intersection of the two curves which is above the $x$-axis can be found to be $(1,\sqrt{24})$. So we are to calculate
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt{24}} \biggl( 5 - \frac{3y^2}{8} \biggr) \, dy, 
$$
which is seen to be equal to $2\sqrt{24}$.

Is the procedure of my reasoning correct? Is the result acquired correct? I only consider myself a novice in integral calculus hence I seek constant affirmation from the more professional. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $y^2 = 8x+16 \implies x = \frac {y^2 - 16}{8}.$   Fix that and you should be fine.

Comment: Often some quick estimates can help you identify mistakes; e.g. a bounding square, x from -2 to 7, y from 0 to $\sqrt{24}$; gives an upper limit of $9\sqrt{24}$, and a lower limit you could take the area of the contained triangle; $\frac{9}{2}\sqrt{24}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is correct, but you made a small sign error in solving for $x$ for one of the boundary curves:
$$
y^2 = 8x + 16 
\iff
x = \frac{y^2 \color{red}{-} 16}{8}, 
$$
hence the integrand is
$$
\frac{28-y^2}{4} - \frac{y^2-16}{8} 
= \color{red}{9} - \frac{3y^2}{8}. 
$$
This produces the result
$$
6\sqrt{24} = 12\sqrt{6} \approx 29.394\ldots
$$
which you can visualize [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9dl7bt1kf6).

---

Incidentally, as a calculus instructor, I would reward you most of the credit for this answer, even though it's not correct, as you show clear understanding of the problem, a strategy for solving it, and even do *most* of the mechanics correctly too.

Comment: Ack, such a blatant error! Thank you very much for your time and effort, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Solution:

$y^2=8x+16$, $y=\mp\sqrt{8x+16}$ and for $y=0, x=-2$

$y^2=-4x+28$, $y=\mp\sqrt{-4x+28}$ and for $y=0, x=7$

$y^2=8x+16=-4x+28$, $x=1$

$$\text{area}=\int_{-2}^{1} \sqrt{8x+16} \ dx + \int_{1}^{7} \sqrt{-4x+28}\ dx=$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{24} \sqrt{u} \ du + (-\frac{1}{4})\int_{24}^{0} \sqrt{v}\ dv=$$
$$=4\sqrt6 + 8\sqrt6=12\sqrt6$$

$u=8x+16, \ du=8\ dx$, $v=-4x+28, \ dv=-4\ dx$

Comment: Else, it's easier to integrate the inverse with coordinates reversed.